# There isn't webapp folder when I create a Spring Web App

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, model-view-controller

I'm creating a webapp with Jar and Maven build but when I create the project I can't find the view layer: there aren't `web-app` , `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` folders.
I want put my jsp pages into my project but I haven't View layer.

There's the pom:
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>EonEsports</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EonEsports</name>
    <description>EonEsports</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`

And there's the project structure
[image]

I was expecting to have a webapp or a WebContent folder where I could put my Jsp pages.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of project you selected initially.
for example if You're using IntelliJ and selected Spring initializr. type, It does not create a webapp folder.

You can manually create a webapp folder below src->main directory and put your Jsp files there.

**Update:**

In case of getting 404 error, or controller not recognizing jsp files,
try adding below changes

first add below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

plus, add these two lines to your application.properties file (assuming Jsp files are put in path: webapp/WEB-INF/)

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: but When I run the application my Controller class doesn't see Jsp pages, I think I have to change artifacts settings but I don't know how

Comment: check the update I added to my answer @kevinpcf